# User has denied the privileges to the code error during applet running

Tags: java, security, applet

I deployed an applet but when I try to access it using "applet" tag, it gives below error,but applet gets run when I run it from eclipse using eclipse "Run as Java Applet" option.

[image]

Comment: ..Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is that you opted not to block the application, but you still run into the 'application blocked' exception. I am answering this because this is what I am facing now.

The browser context is different from Eclipse and the browser's java-plugin will block unsigned jars which try to perform trusted operations. You need to provide more details so that others can help you out here. Different platforms and browsers add to the confusion. Try to debug this problem using the appletviewer tool first - it will help in clearing the first line of issues.

Comment: Did you try adding your webpage/site to the exception list ?

Comment: Guess this was addressed to Adnan. I don't think adding to the exception list will solve this; the JAR needs to be signed at least with a self signed certificate.